# AngularJS Directive parameter set by http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

So I have this directive whose property value is the result of an http call. The html looks like this:

```
<div class="kit-template" kd-kit="controller.kit.data" garment="childController.garment.data"></div>
```

the problem is with the garment property.
Sometimes, the garment property is null which is to be expected because it is still executing the http request.
In other directives I would do something like:

```
if (garment) {
    // Execute some code
}
```

but in this directive I have this bit of code:

```
// Create our svgPath
scope.svgPath = 'assets/garments/' + scope.garment.slug + '.svg';

// Function to execute after the svg has loaded
scope.loaded = function () {

    // For all our garments
    for (var i = 0; i < scope.kit.garments.length; i++) {

        // Get the current garment
        var garment = scope.kit.garments[i];

        // If we find the garment in question
        if (garment.slug === scope.garment.slug) {

            // Show our selected design
            showDesign(element, scope.kit);

            // Apply our colours
            applyColours(scope.kit, garment);
        }
    }
}
```

and the directive template looks like this:

```
<div ng-include="svgPath" onload="loaded()"></div>
```

So the problem I have is that when the SVG has loaded I execute some code, this will only happen once. If the garment is null then it will throw an error. 
What I would like to do is delay the include until the garment has loaded.

Does anyone know how I can solve this paradox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dependent on `garment.data` you can simply use an `ng-if`:

```
<div class="kit-template" 
     kd-kit="controller.kit.data" 
     garment="childController.garment.data"
     ng-if="childController.garment.data"></div>
```

That will delay the execution of the directive until you have the data, and by then you'll have nothing to worry about.